# ruby 1.9.2 installations error on rvm

Tags: ruby, rvm, compilation

I tried to install ruby 1.9.2  on rvm, but after the computer compiles for a while, the system says error message on Terminal. Do you know what the matter is? It's taking me hours :(

```
ruby-1.9.2-head - #fetching 
HEAD is now at 91799a2 merges r30786, r30787 and r30797 from trunk into ruby_1_9_2.
From https://github.com/ruby/ruby
 * branch            ruby_1_9_2 -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
Copying from repo to src path...
Running autoconf
ruby-1.9.2-head - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.2-head - #compiling 
ERROR: Error running 'make ', please read /Users/nofear38/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-head/make.log
ERROR: There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Answer (score 6):

Run `rvm notes` and ensure that OS dependencies are installed.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the build tools from XCode installed? You will need them if you want to `make` things.

Comment: It definitely looks like it can't find gcc/make in order to build ruby.  Can you type "make" at the command line?  Is it on your PATH?

Answer (score 2):

The error output is specifically saying to read `/Users/nofear38/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.2-head/make.log`. What does that log file tell you about the error? That might tell you exactly what the problem is.

If not, what command did you use when you installed RVM?

Are you following the [Installation Methods](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/rvm/install) or some other instructions? All too often we find people have either followed the wrong directions, didn't follow the directions completely, or are using the system-wide installation instead of the single-user's sandbox.

The command output you show is not what I see when installing Ruby via RVM for the current 1.9.2 install. If you used:

```
rvm install 1.9.2-head
```

I recommend instead you use:

```
rvm install 1.9.2
```

which will pull in 1.9.2-p180, which is the current stable branch, rather than the latest bleeding-edge version.

Answer (score 0):

In case you haven't solved this problem, I'm running Ubuntu 11.0 and I used `sudo apt-get install ruby-rvm` and rvm installed perfectly!